# Sorting arrays in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

H have json document with array. As I can't add to beginning of array with push or addtoset I need to sort array. Example

```
{
  "Component": [
    {
      "Id": "PDP-1",
      "Links": {"Link": [
          {
            "Text": "Western Division",
            "Url": "/1x7-en70ai/last-minute-holidays-western-division",
            "Title": "Last minute holidays Western Division"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Browse Regions ",
            "Url": "/1x7-en6uly-10ts/last-minute-holidays-gambia/regions",
            "Title": "Last minute holidays Gambia",
            "Style": "BrowseForMore"
          },
          {
            "Text": "City of Banjul",
            "Url": "/1x6-en6vq7/holidays-city-of-banjul",
            "Title": "City of Banjul Holidays"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Western Division",
            "Url": "/1x6-en70ai/holidays-western-division",
            "Title": "Western Division Holidays"
          }
        ]},
      "Title": "Regions",
      "Type": "PDP"
    },
    {
      "Id": "PDP-2",
      "Links": {"Link": [
          {
            "Text": "Bijilo",
            "Url": "/1x7-enbmy6/last-minute-holidays-bijilo",
            "Title": "Last minute holidays Bijilo"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Browse Cities ",
            "Url": "/1x7-en6uly-10tt/last-minute-holidays-gambia/cities",
            "Title": "Last minute holidays Gambia",
            "Style": "BrowseForMore"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Banjul Beach",
            "Url": "/1x6-enakgm/holidays-banjul-beach",
            "Title": "Banjul Beach Holidays"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Bijilo",
            "Url": "/1x6-enbmy6/holidays-bijilo",
            "Title": "Bijilo Holidays"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Brufut Heights",
            "Url": "/1x6-encok8/holidays-brufut-heights",
            "Title": "Brufut Heights Holidays"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Kololi",
            "Url": "/1x6-enpnle/holidays-kololi",
            "Title": "Kololi Holidays"
          },
          {
            "Text": "Kotu",
            "Url": "/1x6-enq067/holidays-kotu",
            "Title": "Kotu Holidays"
          }
        ]},
      "Title": "Cities",
      "Type": "PDP"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "118431",
  "Template": {
    "PageTemplate": {
      "Code": "2B2",
      "text": "041 - TEMP2 - COP_CONCOU_{LAST MINUTE}"
    },
    "Category": {
      "Code": "1X7",
      "Type": "Product",
      "text": "Last minute holidays"
    },
    "GeoObject": {
      "Code": "EN6ULY",
      "text": "Gambia, The"
    },
    "GeoObjectType": {
      "Code": "1A",
      "text": "Political"
    },
    "GeoObjectSubType": {
      "Code": "10TR",
      "text": "Country"
    }
  },
  "Type": "Content",
  "Url": "/1x7-en6uly/last-minute-holidays-gambia",
  "_id": {"$oid": "528492d4c90fa9fcd0436929"}
}
```

I want to sort this by Style in Links.Link 'BrowseForMore'. Any idea how to do it? I thought I could add dummy array with push which could then sort it the way I want. Any help appreciated

Comment: If you formatted the code, it'd be easier to answer.

Comment: formatted. hopefully better to reaed

Comment: What do you mean by "sort this by Style in Links.Link 'BrowseForMore'"?

Comment: I have array with text, url, title and one with added field style. I want the one with style to be the last entry in array

Comment: This is because I cant find with to addtoset to beginning of array not end of array

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to update the array and keep the sort order with your Links.Link.Style value at the front of the list. In which case use the [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier with update.

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $push: { "Links.Link: {$each: [doc], $sort { Style: -1 }}} }
)
```

The [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator is required even if there is only one document, but can take many.

if you are trying to use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to maintain unique documents the official MongoDB line is that **sets** are considered to be unordered and hence the modifiers are not available here.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what to do to replace [doc] in your example as there are three or four fields e.g.text,url,title and style. Shouldnt it therefore be:

Comment: db.collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $push: { "Links': {$each: [Link], $sort { Style: -1 }}} }
)

Comment: In my answer .."can take many". The argument to $each is a list. Separate the values or variables ( placeholders for vars I used are `id` and `doc` respectively ) with commas in between the [ ]. The link on the $each operator in the answer has all the documentation.

Comment: I did this adding a dummy record and documentation said $sort will only work with $slic db.PD1.update
(
    {
         Id: '177032'
        //,'Component.Title': 'Cities'
    },
    {
        $push:
        {
            'Component.Links.Link':
            {
                $each: [ {Text: '111'}, {Url: '111'}, {Title: '111'},{Style:  '1'}], $sort: { Style: -1 },$slice: -10
            }
        }
    }

) but doc not added or sorted

Comment: if you can take the example and sort so 'Browse Regions' is at bottom of array then that would be great. If not then thanks for your help anyway. It seems push will not sort unless you add at least one $each which is why I added dummy and hopefully could use $pull to remove it

Comment: Thanks for your great help. It now works db.PD1.update
(
    {
         Id: '177032'
        ,'Component.Title': 'Cities'
    },
    {
        $push:
        {
            'Component.$.Links.Link' :
            {
                 $each: [{Text: '111', Url: '111', Title: '111',Style:  '1'} ]
                ,$sort: { Style: 1 },$slice: -14
            }
        }
    }

)